# Need to bind data to input type checkbox

Tags: asp.net

I need to bind data to a html input type checkbox.. 
it is inside a gridview and this is my code for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value='<%# Eval("ProjectId") %>' oninit="onl(this)" 
checked="<%# Eval("CanBeInherited") %>"  onclick="showvalue(this)"  />
```

Is this possible? or do i need to use other means of changing the checked property of a checkbox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
runat="server"
```

and

```
id="CheckBoxInheritance"
```

it should run.